# go data type of number field retrieved from mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, go, types

Retrieve mongodb document as `map[string]interface{}` with go driver

Since MongoDB's field type is loose, what's the exact type of a number field retrieved from mongo document? could we write code more robustly?

```
var data map[string]interface{}
col.FindOne(nil, map[string]interface{}{"uid": uid}).Decode(&data)

currLevelInt := 1
currLevel, ok := data["currLevel"]
if ok {
  currLevelInt = int(currLevel.(int32)) // what if here currLevel is not a int32 but a int64 or float or something?
}
```

What if there `currLevel` is not an int32 but an int64 or float or something? Is there a safe way of doing that?

Comment: reflect.TypeOf?

Comment: If you know the field is an integer type, decode it to a struct containing an int field, and let the driver convert it.

Comment: @Para thanks, is reflect fast enough in go?

Comment: @BurakSerdar, thanks, but I am afraid can't do that for this case, since the document's structure is variable.

Comment: In that case, you can use a type switch to convert different numeric types to int, or use `reflect.ValueOf(currLevel).Int()`